# mapping on one of two columns / many-to-many mapping with fluentnhibernate

Tags: join, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I'm trying to map the following:

A user can be connected to another user. The user class has a 'Connections' property which a collection of UserConnection. A UserConnection has two references to User, one for the *requester* (he who initiated the connection) and one for the *requestee* (he who is the target of the connection).

Using FluentNHibernate I want to load all UserConnections for when loading the User. A User's connections are those where the user's id matches *either* the *requesterId* ***or*** the *requesteeId*.

```
public class User
{
    //....
    public virtual IList<UserConnection> Connections { get; set; }
}

public class UserConnection
{
    //....
    public virtual User Requester { get; set; }
    public virtual User Requestee { get; set; }
}
```

This feels like a many-to-many relationship, but I can't quite wrap my head around it. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

My current User mapping (below) obviously only matches on *one* column...

```
HasMany(x => x.Connections).Inverse().Key(k => k.Columns.Add("Requestee_id")).Fetch.Select().Not.LazyLoad();
```

EDIT 2:

I have considered [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615604/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-a-column-against-one-of-two-columns) but I would prefer to avoid that if possible...

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it 1-many? user has a collection of Connections? But each connection has 1 RequesterUser or 1 RequesteeUser?

This would be a self referencing relation, mapping something like below.

```
    public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Table("Users");
            DynamicUpdate();            
            References<User>(x => x.Requester)
                .Cascade.None()
                .NotFound.Ignore();
            References<User>(x => x.Requestee)
                .Cascade.None()
                .NotFound.Ignore();
            HasMany<User>(x => x.RequesterConnections)
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Inverse()
                .KeyColumn("RequesterId");
            HasMany<User>(x => x.RequesteeConnections)
                .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Inverse()
                .KeyColumn("RequesteeId");
        }
    }
```

I could be totally wrong, not been using NH long but maybe it will spark some ideas.
I think this is how i would try and do it.

Obviously you don't have a single collection of Connections but you could get them both pretty easily.

Hope this helps.
Kohan

Comment: Hi Kohan,

Thanks very much for your reply. I've mapped things pretty much like what you've specified at the moment (with two collections) and that works fine. I'm looking for a way of avoiding two collections, though, as it results in two selects. You're right in that it's a one-to-many relationship - I got my little head confused. Can you explain why you've mapped x.Requester and x.Requestee, above? My User class doesn't have these properties.

Comment: It's due to the mapping working with a self referencing relationship. I thought that you might store all users (normal, requester, requestee) in the same table. So the mapping needs to know what connections are potentially on the user but it also needs to go the other way and know which User is the parent. Possibly this is wrong to have x.Requester, x.Requestee: you could have a ParentUser mapping instead. As was said, a user can have a list of connectionusers but a connectionuser needs a single user to be mapped too. Hope this makes sense.